# C++ How to use enum from a class that also has this class in it

Tags: c++, templates, enums, constants, forward-declaration

I have the following issue:

```
class Bar
{
    std::array<int, Foo::Baz::LEN> array;
};

class Foo
{
    Bar bar;
public:
    enum class Baz
    {
        VAL_1 = 0, VAL_2, LEN
    };
}
```

Is there any way to separate the declaration of the enum class from `Foo` while keeping it in `class Foo`'s namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

You will need to move the definition of the `enum` before the definition of `Bar` or define it inside `Bar`.